# tornado stop response after about 37000 requests

Tags: nginx, concurrency, tornado

I use the nginx+tornado as my web serever.

When I use the ab to do the stress testing, the server always stop response after about 37,000 requests. And if I only use the nginx, the testing is good.

My nginx.conf is like this

> upstream tornado {
>       server 127.0.0.1:8881;
>       server 127.0.0.1:8882;
>       server 127.0.0.1:8883;
>       server 127.0.0.1:8884;
>   }
>
> server {
>       listen 81;
>   
>       #Allow file uploads
>       client_max_body_size 50M;
>   
>       location / {
>       proxy_pass_header Server;
>       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>       proxy_redirect off;
>       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>       proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
>       proxy_pass http://tornado;
>       }
>   }

I use an empty-request handler in tornado server.

> class Hello(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
>       @tornado.web.asynchronous
>       @tornado.web.gen.coroutine
>       def get(self):
>           self.write('hello,I\'m sickee,system is ok...')
>           self.finish()
>   
>   my server is run on centos 6.5 and ulimit -n is 65535,
>   
>   my ab test command is like this:
>       ab -n 80000 -c 200 url  or
>       ab -n 80000 -c 200 url/sid

If I move the location-block in nginx.conf, the testing is ok!
Any of my configure is wrong, or tornado need some configure to support the high concurrency?

thanks

Comment: my machine is 8 cores, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz, 16GB memory.    i use supervisor to start 4 tornado empty server, now i reduce it to 2, the server is running smoothly......